# What does this red background dialog means?

Tags: support, javascript

Recently i saw a dialog with red background appeared in my SO page in Web Browser.

What does it mean? and because of this dialog my SO site is not loaded questions properly..

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means what it states.

Stack Overflow (and all Stack Exchange sites) requires JavaScript from another domain (web site). This was blocked or failed to load for some reason so the site won't work as expected.

Either reload the page and hope that the JavaScript loads this time, or work out what is blocking the external JavaScript.